# Loop and write data to csv file in python

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I try to scrape product info from a website using a list of product's urls, which is stored in csv file
My solution is to iterate the list of urls and scrape info and then store each field of product's info into another csv file.
Here is my first attemp:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  csv

path = r'C:\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\Chromedriver'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

browserdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path,options=chrome_options)

with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\product_link.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        link= row['url']
        print(link)
        #print(link)
        browserdriver.get(link)
        browserdriver.implicitly_wait(10)
        title=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="finfo"]//div[1]//h2').text
        print(title)
        price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="regular-price"]').text
        tomtatsp=browserdriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="cinfo"]')
        tomtatsp_moi=""
        for p in tomtatsp:
            tomtatsp_moi=str(tomtatsp_moi)+str(p.text)+"\n"
        with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\luudulieu_sanpham.csv', mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            fieldnames = ['ten_sp','gia_sp','motasp_ngan']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'ten_sp':str(title),'gia_sp': str(price),'motasp_ngan':str(tomtatsp_moi)})
        print("step 1 done")

print("done")
```

The result I received is a csv file containing only the header row and the info of the last product, which is from the last url in the input csv (product_link.csv).
I think there is something wrong when I write scraped data into the csv file but I do not know how to solve.
Pls, help me to edit my script above. Thank you!

Comment: `mode='w'` here you are always opening it in write mode which replaces the old content.

Comment: You overwrite luudulieu_sanpham.csv each time you open it in write mode. If you want a single file output with all of the data, use `mode='a'` to append.

Comment: Also, if you want all of the data in one file, you should only `writer.writeheader()` once.